# How to get Day and Month from Date Sql Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Date Format : 20-Jun-14

Need Query which return : 20-Jun

Current Date : 20-Jun-2015

So,that it should compare to current date and return as in above case

Total years : 1 year

Comment: Question was not clear enough!!!!

Comment: How to get day and month only from date (20-JUN-14) ? . next part : it should compare with current date let says today is 20-JUN-15 and it should return that 1 year completed as per todays date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cut of parts of a date using `DATEPART`.

See:

```
SELECT DATEPART(day,currentDate), DATEPART(month, currentDate)
```

This way you should be able to compare the dates for example in a `where`-clause.

As the questioner need date not as an Integer, he could use the `DATENAME` function:

```
SELECT DATEPART(day,currentDate), DATENAME(month, currentDate)
```

Due to the fact that `DATENAME` doesn't support the MMM format, you could also use a `CASE` structure.

```
SELECT DATEPART(day,currentDate) as day, 
     CASE DATEPART(month, currentDate)
          WHEN 1 THEN N'JAN'
          WHEN 2 THEN N'FEB'
          WHEN 3 THEN N'MAR'
          WHEN 4 THEN N'APR'
          WHEN 5 THEN N'MAI'
          WHEN 6 THEN N'JUN'
          WHEN 7 THEN N'JUL'
          WHEN 8 THEN N'AUG'
          WHEN 9 THEN N'SEP'
          WHEN 10 THEN N'OCT'
          WHEN 11 THEN N'NOV'
          WHEN 12 THEN N'DEC'
      END as month
```

Comment: it returns month in INTEGER(1,2,3) format .. i need month in MMM format (JUN)

Comment: You can play around with `DATENAME` (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174395(v=sql.120).aspx) But it won't support MMM format. Just mm.

Comment: I've added two additional ways to get the month name.

Comment: thanks let me try @Ionic

Comment: @ManishGoswami If it works for you, you can mark the question as your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To get result as you wish, please use [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) or [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function. Have a look at excellent article too: [SQL Server Functions that helps to convert date and time values to and from string literals and other date and time formats.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576178/cast-convert-format-try-parse-date-and-time-sql)

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd MMM')
```

**Note:** Format function is available in MS SQL Server 2012 and higher!

To return time difference, use [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2014-06-20', GETDATE()) AS YearDiff
```